# About all program in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/nested/parsing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object parsing(@RequestBody JSONObject jsonObject, @RequestBody String Field) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONParser jsonParser1 = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse("jsonObject");
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject1.get("condition");
        for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = (JSONArray) jsonObject2.get("group_1");
            for (int j = 0; j <= jsonArray2.size(); j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject3 = (JSONObject) jsonArray2.get(j);
                JSONArray jsonArray3 = (JSONArray) jsonObject3.get("Queries");
                JSONObject jsonObject4 = (JSONObject) jsonParser1.parse(Field);
                arrayList=(ArrayList) jsonObject4.get("Field");
                //return jsonObject4.get("Field");
            }
        }
        /*JSONArray jsonArray3 = (JSONArray) jsonObject3.get("Queries");
        JSONObject jsonObject4 = (JSONObject) jsonParser1.parse("Field");
        arrayList=(ArrayList) jsonObject4.get("Field");*/
        //return jsonObject4.get("Field");
        return arrayList;
    }
```

Comment: {
  "condition": [
    {
      "group_1": {
        "OP": "AND",
        "Queries": [
          {
            "Field": "Designation",
            "Term": "Vice Precident",
            "QOP": "OR"
          },
          {
            "Field": "Designation",
            "Term": "Delivery Manager",
            "QOP": "OR"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
 }       I want to parse this json syntax in mongodb

Comment: you have provided code its good. But can you please provide some description where you facing issue .

Comment: Please provide a specific question. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to create a good question.